# Jest + React-testing-library - wait for a mocked async function to complete

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library

My `componentDidMount()` fires off a call to an async function but depending on the result of that function, it might not result in any DOM change. Is there any way I can wait for the function to complete in my tests?

Here's an example - the click button is initially disabled. If the async function returns true, the click button should be enabled:

```
    myAsyncFunction.mockImplementation(() => true);
    const {queryByText} = render(<Component />);
    const button = queryByText("Click");
    expect(button).toBeDisabled();
    await waitFor( () => expect(button).not.toBeDisabled() );
    expect(button).not.toBeDisabled();
```

But if it returns false the button stays disabled:

```
    myAsyncFunction.mockImplementation(() => false);   // async returning different value
    const {queryByText} = render(<Component />);
    const button = queryByText("Click");
    expect(button).toBeDisabled();
    await waitFor( () => {} );                       //        <== **** CODE SMELL ****
    expect(button).toBeDisabled();
```

The second test does actually work but the empty `waitFor()` is considsered bad practice. is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: You probably want to fire: `await wait();` after rendering component: 
```const {queryByText} = render(<Component />);
     await wait();
```

Comment: yes, wait() is now deprecated and I beleive that `waitFor(()=>{});` is the new equivalent. However I read somewhere (I think it was in the previous version of the react-testing-library docs) that an empty wait() was considered bad practice and you should wait for something concrete instead

Answer (score 34):

In the docs for [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor), it is recommended to just wait for your async function `.toHaveBeenCalled` like so

```js
await waitFor(() => expect(mockAPI).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1))
```

Comment: Aha! thanks, that text has been updated since I asked the question :-). As I understand it, this would wait for the function to be called, but not wait for the promise to be resolved. However, since it's explicit in the docs now, I guess it's OK

Comment: What is 'mockAPI' here?  Ie, if one is using https://mswjs.io/ as recommended by ReactTestingLibrary, would you pass in the return value of setupServer?  (I tried but got confusing results which don't indicate whether it's working or not.)

Comment: This is a direct quote from the [testing-library docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor), in that context `mockAPI` is the name they are using to refer to _any asynchronous function you might need to wait for_ before your expectation can be asserted.